# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Пишу недавно, так что не судите строго.
У меня возникла проблема с программой.
Консоль сборки пишет:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A::Zn::n", referenced from:
      A::Zn::set_n(unsigned int) in main.o
      A::Zn::operator+(A::Zn) in main.o
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

namespace A
{
class Zn
{
    static unsigned int n;
    unsigned int v;
public:
    Zn(unsigned int v0) : v (v0) {}
    Zn operator + (Zn b)
    {
        Zn t(0);
        t.v = (v + b.v) % t.n;
        return t;
    }
    unsigned int get_v ()
    {
    return v;
    }
    static void set_n(unsigned int n0);
};
void Zn::set_n(unsigned int n0)
{
    n = n0;
}
}

#endif // HEADER_H
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <header.h>

int main()
{
  using namespace A;
  Zn::set_n(6);
  Zn a(5);
  Zn b(5);
  Zn c(5);
  c=a+b;
  std::cout << c.get_v() << '\n';
}
```

Сам компилятор выдаёт

```
ошибка: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Прям не знаю что делать. 
Заранее всем спасибо за ответ.

Comment: По мелочам: (1) для оператора сложения лучше использовать `Zn operator + (const Zn& b)`, чтобы не создавались лишние копии, (2) в том же операторе + недостаточно взять `%`, т. к. для отрицательной суммы ответ будет неожиданным (проверьте!). Вам придётся проверять знак и делать поправку.

Comment: Для начала неплохо рассказать какой компилятор (среда) используются. Судя по всему - что-то из MSVC++. Также мне неясно зачем сделано `static unsigned int n;` именно `static`

Comment: @gecube: ТС хочет смоделировать элемент [циклической группы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0). `n` — общий размер группы.

Comment: [Гомоморфный образ группы,
(Будь во имя коммунизма)
Изоморфен фактор-группе
По ядру гомоморфизма.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Факторгруппа)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно же просто проинициализировать статическую переменную где-то вне объявления класса и ошибка исчезнет.

Например так:

```
unsigned int Zn::n = 666;
void Zn::set_n(unsigned int n0)
{
    n = n0;
}
```

По остальным частям кода VladD вроде дал неплохой комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло! Просто идеально, все работает.